# android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager#popBackStackImmediate() results in a NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-support-library, fatal-error

Sometimes executing `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager#popBackStackImmediate()` results in the next exception:

```
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
> virtual method 'android.os.Handler
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()' on a null
> object reference
>        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1588)
>        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
>        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:585)
```

Here is my code:

```
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        manager.popBackStackImmediate();
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Does anyone knows what could be the reason for that?

Comment: did you using any `Handler` ??

Comment: Can you post your code??

Comment: more context please?

Comment: You could find a workaround here (the post on the bottom of the page): https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183920. OR (my personal supposition): Since it seems to be a bug affecting API Level 23, maybe you could target a previous API Level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved back from compile `'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'` to compile `'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'` and now it doesn't happen any more.
So to conclude, it seems like there is a bug with `support-v4:23.1.1.`

Answer (score 0):

this might work set noHistory flag false for the hosting activity