# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException while using ViewPager

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, fragment

I am using ViewPager in my app to show 3 fragments in tabs. Following Crash is being reported in the Dev Console without any detailed pointer to the problem

Error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Handler
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()' on a null
>   object reference

And following is the crash detail -

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Handler android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()' on a null object reference
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1613)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:633)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18880)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18880)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18880)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18880)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18880)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18880)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18880)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18880)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2650)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18880)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2104)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1220)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1456)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1111)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6017)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Anyone faced similar problem and what could be solution?

Comment: post your java code here.

Comment: kindly post your code , might be an issue how you're using FragmentManager and check this thread 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332900/android-support-v4-app-fragmentmanagerpopbackstackimmediate-results-in-a-null

Comment: post code,another suggestion would be to use this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: This is probably related to this open issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208911

Answer (score 0):

I faced this also sometime. I don't know if you using Handler (android.os.handler) in this case. If you are using then make sure you have initialized it on onCreate. After initializing this I have solved this such type of log cat error